# CodeIgniter set_value() is poplating values in a different form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two forms in a single page

1. Create Record Form
2. Update Record Form

Create Record form works perfectly but when I use the Update Record form the values are populated in the Create Form when an error occurs. What can be done to prevent this or any better structure to be followed for creating such functionality.

Comment: can you paste your code so we can check

Comment: Could have done that but it is implemented in a very complex scenario, to make it simple to understand I explained it like this. but anyways thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dharma Sai Teja - Please make sure that the names provided to the fields should be unique in all form. The values will be populated wrong if the

Comment: you can use comment for this statement

Comment: thanks @Rushikesh yup this worked perfectly, it was such a simple thing but did not get my thought.

Comment: @Dharma Sai Teja - Welcome buddy